# vba xlrunningtotal not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a filed as running total, when its added as just xlsum it works but not when I try to make it xl running total.

```
    .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        sShtname).PivotFields("my_fav_100"), "my_fav_100_2", xlSum
    .PivotFields("my_fav_100_2").Calculation = xlRunningTotal
    With pt.PivotFields("my_fav_100_2")
       .Style = "Comma"
       .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""0""??_);_(@_)"
```

No compilation error, but gets `N/A` in the field, if I comment out the `".PivotFields("my_fav_100_2").Calculation = xlRunningTotal"` field gets populated but simply a sum not running total sum, also tried  .`Calculation = xlRunningTotal` and does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are providing enough information for the way `xlRunningTotal` is designed to operate. You need to define the `BaseField` property to pair with your xlRunningTotal setting. When I choose ***Running Total In*** from the user interface, I have to pick a column and when I mock it up in code I see the same error you see until I add the line `.BaseField = myColName` after `.Calculation = xlRunningTotal`.

Comment: yes you are right it was picking a default basefield and now  adding the code you suggested it works smoothly. thank you